# How to insert non unicode txt file in to mysql by php?

Tags: php, mysql, unicode

I have a non Unicode text file that generate by a software and i want import it by php into mysql, I can import it in a specific table and my collation of table and all of fields is utf8_general_ci, but when imported some fields such as name,family,fathername not be readable, the text file that generated is in ANSI unicode type and i want  import it into table of DB.
this is some code of my program in bellow.
code:

```
<form action="" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data"      `name`="FileSendAmzForm" onsubmit="return checktit();"  accept-charset="utf-8_general_ci">
            <table><tr><td class="td1">
                 <input type="file" name="infemp1" /></td><td class="td1"><p>send file infemp</p></td></tr>
                 <tr><td class="td1"><input type="file" name="infempvam1"  /></td><td class="td1"><p>send file infempvam</p></td></tr>
                 <tr><td class="td1"><input type="file" name="infempamz1" /></td><td class="td1"><p>send file infempamz</p></td></tr>
            <tr><td class="td1"><p><input type="submit" method="post" value="send files"name='submit' /></p></td></tr>
            </table>
            </form>
<?php
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);
mysqli_query ($conn,"set character_set_client='utf8'");
mysqli_query ($conn,"set character_set_results='utf8'");
mysqli_query ($conn,"set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
//mysqli_query($conn,"set collation_connection='utf8_persian_ci'");
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"set character_set_client='utf8'");
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"set character_set_results='utf8'") ;
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'") ;
//mysqli_set_charset($conn,"set collation_connection='utf8_persian_ci'");
if (!$conn)
  {
  die('Have Problem: ' . mysql_error());
  }
// code of load file 
          $result = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE'".$myFile."' INTO TABLE infemp COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','";
mysqli_query($conn,$result);
// ofter this &myfile imported to infemp but fields mentioned not read or emptay.
?>
```

Comment: "ANSI unicode type" — what does that mean? You should get a basic understanding of what Unicode and UTF-8 are. See for instance [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: the text file that create is in ANSI Unicode not in UTF in default, for example we can create a text file and see the Unicode type is ANSI, i want get data of text into MySQL while all of the fields readable.

Comment: (1) Read the linked article. (2) Then read [how to use the mysqli_set_charset function](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysqli_set_charset).

You can't solve this problem because your server doesn't know which code page the client used to save the file. ANSI means different things depending on the language setting on your system.

Comment: Figure out what encoding you have in the INFILE.  _Then_ use `mysqli_set_charset` to match _that_.  Meanwhile, use utf8 for the column(s) in the table.

Comment: All of my fields in db has utf8_general_ci   collation mode, i don't have any encoding structure in INFILE statement and think don't exists any structure in it, ofter study on this issue i believe best way is find a method  such as "How to convert ANSI file to UNICODE in mysql by php?"